# adding hover to images added via .html (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I first run an ajax request on my server to receive my image data
then I do the following to add all images received from the server to the website:

```
var image="";
  for (var i = receivedData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //received data is the stuff coming from server
    image+="<a href='letterView.php?id=".concat(receivedData[i].ID);
    image+="''><img class='individualImages'";
    image+="id=letterImage_'".concat(i);
    image+="' src=images/244x200/";
    image+=receivedData[i].ID;
    image+=".png alt='image' ></a>";

  }
  $('.letters').html(image);
```

I thought I could now use the IDs to add a hover effect to the images (change the images on hover) but I cannot figure out how to go about that.
Could anyone please help? thanks in advance!

Comment: how change the images?? or what efect?

Comment: css pseudo selector :hover should help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: You can do as you would if it was already in the DOM. Using Javascript or CSS.

Comment: Do all the images need different effects? If not, just use `.individualImages:hover {}` and your styles would go in the curly brackets. If you need each effect to be different, you'll have to do it with a script.

Comment: @Danko: changing the source of the image .attr('src', 'example.png') where example.png is different with all images.

Comment: @ShengSlogar: no they all need different source-images when hovering....

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/nqS6L/1/
This can be done inside the `for loop`. You can use `class`  Or  `ID` and loop through.

I added new `div0` to show/hide on hover just as an example. You can do your logic whatever you want to `show/hide` on hover. I also added some data to `receivedData` in order for the example to work, make it more clear.
`receivedData = [  {"ID": "product1"},
    {"ID": "product2"},
    {"ID": "product3"}];`

```
$(".individualImages").hover(function() {
    $("#div0").show(); 
}, function() {
    $("#div0").hide(); 
});
```

Added the logic after appending the images to the DOM. Meaning after this line 
`$('.letters').html(image);` You can add a for loop again and do it hover using `ID` and hence show/hide different things based on the `id` of the image.

Comment: so what would I put in the function here?
I tried
$( "img.individualImages" ).attr('src',"image.png" );
but it doesn't even seem to get called (tried with a console log on hover and nothing happens...